# Pinch zooming to multiple images in view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, nsuserdefaults, pinchzoom

I am new in Ios & learning It.
I am creating application based on images.
I have multiple images in my viewcontroller, Which i had passed throgh another view controller(Named as a View2) via Nsuser default as below.

```
NSString *str11 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"Vishal"];
NSLog(@"%@",str11);
if(![str11 isEqualToString:@""])
{

   img12 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:str11]];

   img12.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,100,100);

   [secondview addSubview:img12];

  [self.view addSubview:secondview];
```

Here In key "Vishal" I have bunch of 5 images.
Which i passed to Uiimageview *img12 in my view controller.
which i had push to my view controller.

I want to zoom these images.

Now I want to assign pinch zooming to all my images.
I had listen like You have to provide another view for Zooming.
now i am stuck at how to assign view to every images which are comes from another viewcontroller.
And how i knew which image user is tryng to pinch zooming.

Please Help me.

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html ) link. I have used it a lot, and it has helped be several times.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with multiple images, you will need to have a separate view for this purpose. I am providing all the steps:

Steps:

1. You need to create a separate view.
2. Add scrollview on is nibt.
3. Add an imageview on scroll view.
4. Add all zoom delegate methods, for zoom feature, in this class only like viewForZoomingInScrollView etc.
5. In viewForZoomingInScrollView return this imageview.

Now where you were adding images

1. In you image array loop create separate instance of this new class.(Suppose you have five images you will have to create five instances)
2. Add those images to this new class's imageview.

Now you are  able to add zoom separately on every images without bothering how many images you have.

With this approach you can optimize your code as well. Suppose you will have more than 10 images , thet you can load only two instances of this class and reuse those view turn by turn according to your need, to show the images when user swipes.

Comment: Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: IS there any way to do this stuff without using UIScrollview?

Comment: You will need scrollview to apply zoom.